# CircleProgressDrawable setColorSchemeColors() doesnt work

Tags: android, kotlin, android-glide

i wanna create a new **CircleProgressDrawable** and assing it to the **Glide** placeholder, so when the image is loading, the user could see the loading animation

I have tried this

```
val progressDrawable = CircularProgressDrawable(context).apply {
        strokeWidth = 15f

        setColorSchemeColors(R.color.standard_blur,
            R.color.standard,
            R.color.standard_light,
            R.color.standard75)
        start()
    }
```

but the setColorSchemeColors isnt working, my circle drawable looks full dark, anyone know what is happening there?

Comment: okay, i fixed it, i didnt get the color correctly i was just referencing the colorId but not picking up the color itself with the 'getColor(R.color.standard)' function

Comment: but now i got another question, can i change the size of that drawable when i assing it to the placeholder, cause is see it very big and i want make it smaller

Answer (score 0):

Try to place a **Dialog** with the loading progress in your main view.
It's more intuitive and people won't get so confused :)